# How to set shortcuts to screenshot on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, mate, screenshot

In Ubuntu Mate version 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial)
, I want to create a shortcut like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to screenshot, but I am not able to find where to do it.

When I go to **Preferences -> Keyboard and Mouse -> Keyboard** I do not find a way to set it there.

For the moment I type on Terminal: `bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 mate-screenshot -a"` to take a screenshot of a specific area, or mate-screenshot for the whole screen, but that is not practical.

Anyway on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open MATE Control Center, then click on **Keyboard Shortcuts** (or while using *Ubuntu MATE* panel layout — **System→Preferences→Hardware→Keyboard Shortcuts**).
Also you can open it from terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt with `mate-keybinding-properties`.

Here in **Custom Shortcuts** I have
**Area screenshot to file** with `mate-screenshot -a -i` command
and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> shortcut.

Above:

- `-a` means `--area` to "Grab an area of the screen instead of the entire screen".
- `-i` means `--interactive` to "Interactively set options" (it a workaround, on my systems it does not work without it)

In `dconf` syntax it is written as:

```
dconf load / << EOF
[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom1]
action='mate-screenshot -a -i'
binding='<Shift>Print'
name='Area screenshot to file'
EOF
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I hope I am not wrong, but I think I do not have that **System** entry on the menu at all, I will check that when I open again my computer (I did not expect to get an answer on weekend). If I find that path on my computer, I will accept your answer, for the moment +1, thank you.